# Ruby on Rails: Configure API in initializer in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails app with an API in `lib`. Files in `lib` are autoloaded, and the API is configured in an initializer.

```
# lib/my_api.rb
module MyApi
  extend Configuration
end

# lib/my_api/configuration.rb
module MyApi
  module Configuration
    attr_accessor :my_setting
    def configure
      yield self
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/my_api.rb
MyApi.configure do |config|
  config.my_setting = 'foo'
end
```

This works in production, but in development the API gets configured when the server is started. After I change some code, the configuration is lost and there are errors because the settings are `nil`:

```
irb(main):001:0> MyApi.my_setting
=> "foo"
irb(main):002:0> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
irb(main):003:0> MyApi.my_setting
=> nil
```

My guess is that in development, the classes are reloaded, but the initializer is not, which means it only gets configured once after starting the server.

Right now I'm duplicating my configuration in `lib/my_api.rb`, but that's very hacky.

What's a clean solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, until someone comes up with a better solution, I've come up with two workarounds. I went with 2.

1. Don't autoload the `lib` directory (meaning don't autoload the API). That means having to restart the server when the API code changes, but solves the problem. That's why configuring gems like this works -- because they aren't autoloaded.
2. Manually reload the initializer in development at the end of `lib/my_api.rb`:

   `load Rails.root.join('config/initializers/smart_meter.rb') if Rails.env.development?`

The `MyApi` constant will be replaced by a new one when Rails autoloads classes. The configuration is still available on the old object:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
irb(main):001:0> MyApi.my_setting
=> "foo"
irb(main):002:0> OldMyApi = MyApi
=> MyApi
irb(main):003:0> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
irb(main):004:0> MyApi.my_setting
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> OldMyApi.my_setting
=> "foo"
irb(main):006:0> load Rails.root.join('config/initializers/smart_meter.rb')
=> true
irb(main):007:0> MyApi.my_setting
=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module MyApi
  module Configuration
    mattr_accessor :my_setting
    def configure
      yield self
    end
  end
end
```

[`mattr_accessor`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) is an ActiveSupport macro for creating module level accessors.

Comment: According to the docs, `mattr_accessor` "Defines both class and instance accessors for class attributes." It doesn't change anything related to autoloading, which unfortunately means it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: By defining the attribute on the class you only need to run the initailizer once,  when rails reloads the class it will still hold the varable.

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't make a difference. I'm guessing the class is reloaded, which means it's a different class instance in memory. The configuration is on the old class instance, not the new one.
In rails console, calling `MyApi.my_setting` correctly returns `foo`, after `reload!` `MyApi.my_setting` returns `nil`

Comment: The problem is actually your configure method. Try setting `MyModule.my_setting = 'foo'` in your initializer.

Comment: Since the config method yields `self`, that's actually the same:
`irb(main):001:0> object_id = nil; SmartMeter.configure { |c| object_id = c.object_id }; SmartMeter.object_id == object_id` returns `true`

Comment: I agree with amiuhle - I don't think this helps if the Configuration constant is getting autoreloaded.